# Adding column to sheet with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

In my google sheet the last column with data is "S" . I'm trying to create a script which will loop through the rows and place 'test' in column T if the value in S starts with "FIN"

```
function daysSinceContact() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("test_sheet");
  var main_rows = mainSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var updated = [];
  for (i in main_rows) {
    var row = main_rows[i]
       if ((row[18].substring(0, 3) == 'FIN') ) {
         Logger.log(row[18])
           row[19]=='test'
       }

    updated.push(row);
  }
  var main_range = mainSheet.getDataRange();
  mainSheet.getDataRange().setValues(updated);

}
```

However when I run this I see nothing in column T. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modifications?

#### Modification points :

- When it substitutes `'test'` for `row[19]`, it uses `row[19]='test'`.

  - This is pointed out by @Crazy Ivan
- For the rows without `'FIN'`, `''` is added to `row[19]`.

  - By this, the length of each element in 2 dimensional array becomes the same.
- The range retrieved by `getDataRange()` is different from that of the current data. Because one column was added.

  - So `getRange(1, 1, updated.length, updated[0].length)` is used.

The modified script which was reflected above points is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function daysSinceContact() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("test_sheet");
  var main_rows = mainSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var updated = [];
  for (i in main_rows) {
    var row = main_rows[i]
       if ((row[18].substring(0, 3) == 'FIN') ) {
         Logger.log(row[18])
           row[19] = 'test'
       } else {
         row[19] = ''; // Added
       }

    updated.push(row);
  }
  // var main_range = mainSheet.getDataRange(); // This is not used.
  mainSheet.getRange(1, 1, updated.length, updated[0].length).setValues(updated); // Modified

}
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @user61629 Welcome.Thank you, too.